# getting worksheet by name in vsto workbook application

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

This code add a worksheet to my workbook in a VSTO excel workbook application via a ribbon:

```
Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();
Excel.Window window = e.Control.Context;
Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet =((Excel.Worksheet)window.Application.ActiveSheet);
```

The added worksheet is also the active one (obviously). How can I get existing worksheets in workbook application - ideally by name?

This gives me (before I add the worksheet above) 2 correctly as there are 2 worksheets:

```
var nows = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count;
```

One would think that I can access the worksheet at least by index like so:

```
var ws = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets[0];
```

but this throws this exception:

> $exception {"Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))"} System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Any ideas? Ideally, I would like to access the worksheets via **name**. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**  Sorry I missed your last line where you say:

> Ideally, I would like to access the worksheets via **name**. Thanks!

Actually Excel Ole Automation allows you to access a worksheet by name by the **same** indexer:

Instead of:

```
var ws = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
```

...just use:

```
var ws = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets["Foo"];
```

The c# looking indexer is actually short-hand in this case for:

```
var ws = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Foo");
```

...where the argument passed in `Item()` is an object (well `Variant` as far as COM is concerned). Convention for COM collections is to expose an Item property that takes a parameter (yes you read that right) but VB and .NET simplify it.

[Tell me more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheets.item.aspx)

---

### Original Answer:

Excel Interop via .NET is by way of Ole Automation which historically goes way back to the days where most things was accesssed via Visual Basic (no not VB.NET) applications which used *1-based arrarys* and **not** `0`.

The correct syntax to access the first element is therefor:

```
var ws = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
```

Comment: Thanks makes sense - but I do not necessarily know that index 1 is workbook X and index 2 is workbook Y. I guess I need to figure index to name mapping via worksheet.Name?

Comment: @cs0815 It is no different to you if they were utilising zero-based arrays.  Mapping is still required

Comment: @cs0815 Please see update.  I did not see your last sentence in question

Answer (score 5):

You could use LINQ to query the collection for the name of the `Worksheet` you're interested in.

The following returns the single matching `Worksheet` or `null`.

```
var worksheet =
    Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Cast<Worksheet>()
                                   .SingleOrDefault(w => w.Name == "worksheet_name");
```

If there could be several with the same name, use `Where()` and `ToList()` instead.

```
var worksheet =
    Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Cast<Worksheet>()
                                   .Where(w => w.Name == "worksheet_name")
                                   .ToList();
```